# Class 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout' not found (SDK Level 25+)

Tags: android, gradle, drawerlayout

In my Android application I'm using Activities that are derived from AppCompatActivity. This requires at some point the DrawerLayout. Therefore I have added

```
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0@aar'
```

to my build.gradle. This worked fine, till I switched to SDK Level 25 - now the build fails with

```
class file for android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout not found
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED.
```

I check the support repo of the SDK on my disk and support-v4-25.1.0.aar doesn't contain the DrawerLayout.class any more. (It has only 2 kb and doesn't contain any classes which were in v4-24+).

I already reinstalled the support repo with the SDK Manager, but I was unable to make this work.

Which library to I have to add to my gradle file in order to make my build work? (compileSdkVersion 25, buildToolsVersion "25.0.2")

Comment: Maybe you're missing `compile 'com.android.support:design:x.x.x'` dependency in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but nope. Didn't work. I also checked the package. The DrawerLayout is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google better modularized popular components from the support-v4/appcompat-v7 libraries into their own libraries with release from 24.1.1 to 24.2.0. So the v4 is empty and you have to integrate the component libraries such as 'support-core-ui'. (https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/4y70e7/android_support_library_v242_released/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Right Click on Project.
2. From top menu: Build Path->Configure Build Path.
3. Tab: Order and Export.
4. Clean & Rebuild your project again.

If that does not work, try "File -> Invalidate catches / Restart"

Comment: I'm building directly from shell using "gradlew clean assemble" as my CI environment is doing it the same way. So that doesn't help.